# How to get all variables in a Cil instruction (OCaml)?

Tags: ocaml, berkeley-cil

I want to add to an instruction in CIL with a comment.
In this comment, I would like to show all variables in that instruction.
I wrote an OCaml module to use CIL driver. The code look like

```
class addCommentVisitor = object
   inherit nopCilVisitor
   method vinst (i: instr) : instr list visitAction = 
   match i with
    | Set(lval, exp, lc) ->
      (* do the job *)
     ...
```

Within the match, how to iterate all the variables in the `instr i`? For example, with the instruction `x[i] = y[j] * (z[k] + l);`, I would like to get the name of variables `x, i, y, j, z, k, l`.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allocate a new visitor, whose method `vvrbl` will match variable uses, and use this visitor to iterate over the variables of the expression with `Cil.visitCilExpr`, accumulating the variables in a mutable list (for instance).

*Edit:* The complete code would look like this.

```ml
class addCommentVisitor = object
  inherit nopCilVisitor
  method vinst (i: instr) : instr list visitAction = 
  match i with
  | Set(lval, exp, lc) ->
      let varVisitor = object
        inherit nopCilVisitor
        val mutable vars : varinfo list = []
        method get_vars = vars
        method vvrbl v = vars <- v :: vars; DoChildren
      end in
      ignore(visitCilLval (varVisitor :> cilVisitor) lval);
      ignore(visitCilExpr (varVisitor :> cilVisitor) exp);
      let vars = varVisitor#get_vars in ...
```

Depending on your code, you could also factor out the inner visitor in its own class instead of using an immediate object, and use a set instead of a list if you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gabriel. Before reading your answer, I did try to implement a method that convert an `Cil.exp` to `varinfo list`. Although it works, my code looks messy compared to yours :)